# Node.JS - is there a cache which is: lightweight, high concurrency, persistent, distributed?

Tags: node.js, caching

i'm using nodejs as a "query" server: client sends http GET http://xxxx:xxx/xxx?key=xxx to node.js, and node.js responses with corresponding value. the value is generated when queried, and i wanna cache it.

what i want for a cache includes:

1. `productive usage`, neither project nor demo.
2. lightweight: the key/value are both just string.
3. high performance: the key set may be 1M, and each key/value may be ~10KB.
4. concurrent:  about ~10M queries per day.
5. persistent: i can store the cache to file system.
6. distributed: the node.js may be a cluster behind NGINX, so the cache should.

i think this is more than a single package, but a solution.

can anyone explain this solution?

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow. You can ask on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but be sure to [provide enough information](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis fits perfectly in most of the features you need as it is in-memory, persistent, high on performance, concurrent, distributed, works well in production and have nodejs integrations available.

Redis is a data structure server. It is open-source, networked, in-memory, and stores keys with optional durability.

Some features are :
 - Transactions 
 - Pub/Sub
 - Lua scripting 
 - Keys with a limited time-to-live
 - LRU eviction of keys 
 - Automatic failover

You can read more about redis [here](http://redis.io/topics/introduction) or [redis-wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis)

You can also refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7897243/2711916) for more on redis.

Comment: many thank for your kind answer! i've got additional questions as to your answer: 1. you say redis is in-memory and persistent, does this give contradiction? 2. as to persistent storage, does redis use mongodb? 3. would you please give a link of redis/mongodb benchmark as a cache? thx again~